# How can I match regex named capturing groups in order

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex for capturing commands in C# console app. User can write multiple commands in the same line. The problem is that those commands are captured not in the order they were written but in the order that regex named capturing groups are written.
For example if user types:

- Q I

Regex below would first catch I and then Q resulting in wrong order of command executions.
Is it possible to fix this within regex?

`^((?<state>I\s?)?()|(?<quit>Q\s?)?()|(?<time>VR (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<connection_type>V (?:PU|PO|OS) (:?S|Z) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<request_file>UR [0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,}\.csv\s?)?()|(?<create_reserved_request>ZD [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|(?<create_request>ZP [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|(?<ship_channel>F [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}( [Q])?\s?)?()|(?<table_formating>T(( P)?()|( Z)?()|( RB)?\s?){1,3})?()|(?<occupied_connections_by_type>ZA (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<print_data>VF(( R)?()|( B)?()|( M)?()|( K)?()|( D)?\s?){1,8})?)*$`

Code:

```cs
string regexCommands = @"(^((?<status_vezova>I\s?)?()|(?<prekid_rada>Q\s?)?()|(?<vrijeme>VR (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()" +
                @"|(?<vezovi_po_vrsti>V (?:PU|PO|OS) (:?S|Z) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|" +
                @"(?<datoteka_zahtjeva>UR [0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,}\.csv\s?)?()|(?<kreiranje_rezerviranog_zahtjev>ZD [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|" +
                @"(?<kreiranje_zahtjeva>ZP [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|(?<komunikacija_brod_kanal>F [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}( [Q])?\s?)?()|" +
                @"(?<format_ispisa_tablica>T(( P)?()|( Z)?()|( RB)?\s?){1,3})?()|(?<zauzeti_vezovi_prema_vrsti>ZA (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<ispis_podataka>VF(( R)?()|( B)?()|( M)?()|( K)?()|( D)?\s?){1,8})?)*$)";

string commands = Console.ReadLine();
Regex regex = new Regex(regexCommands);
Match match = regex.Match(commands);
if (!regex.IsMatch(naredba!))
{
    throw new Exception();
}

List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listRegexGroupsAndValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

//insert all regex named groups and values in list
foreach (string groupName in regex.GetGroupNames())
{
    if (groupName.Length > 2)
        listRegexGroupsAndValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(groupName, groups[groupName].Value));
}


//print
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in listRegexGroupsAndValues)
{
     Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " " + pair.Value);
}
```

This way I have all commands that user has written in one list of key value pairs. Then I can iterate through this list and execute each command by using factory method.

Comment: Regex isn't really the best option here. Instead, you should split on the separator, then examine the result as a stream of tokens. Start by consuming a command. If that command takes an argument, look ahead and see if there's something that can be consumed as an argument (use regex to see if it matches the pattern of the expected argument). Proceed to the next command. Use a state machine to keep track of what you're trying to consume next.

Comment: Please show the code you use to output the result.

Comment: I'd agree with @madreflection and also suggest you take a look at an actual parser library for this type of work. One example is this one: https://github.com/sprache/Sprache

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not allowed to use any kind of additional libraries..

Comment: If my suggestion below resolved the issue for you, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the captures by their Index property. First collect all matches from the relevant groups, then sort by Index of the capture.

```
const string regEx = @"^((?<state>I\s?)?()|(?<quit>Q\s?)?()|(?<time>VR (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<connection_type>V (?:PU|PO|OS) (:?S|Z) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}) (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<request_file>UR [0-9a-zA-Z_-]{1,}\.csv\s?)?()|(?<create_reserved_request>ZD [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|(?<create_request>ZP [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}\s?)?()|(?<ship_channel>F [0-9]{1,} [0-9]{1,}( [Q])?\s?)?()|(?<table_formating>T(( P)?()|( Z)?()|( RB)?\s?){1,3})?()|(?<occupied_connections_by_type>ZA (\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\. \d{2}\:\d{2})\s?)?()|(?<print_data>VF(( R)?()|( B)?()|( M)?()|( K)?()|( D)?\s?){1,8})?)*$";
const string input = "Q I Q";

List<(string commandGroup, string command, int index)> list = new List<(string commandGroup, string command, int index)>();

// Get first match
Match match = Regex.Match(input, regEx);

// When match then get relevant groups
if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
    {
        // that have captures and names which are not numbers
        if (group.Success && !int.TryParse(group.Name, out int ignore))
        {
            // Add all Captures with group name, match value and match index
            foreach(Capture capture in group.Captures)
            {
                list.Add((group.Name, capture.Value, capture.Index));
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    // ... throw Exception
}

// Order by Index that is original position in input
list = list.OrderBy(l => l.index).ToList();

foreach ((string commandGroup, string command, int index) in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(commandGroup + ": " + command);
}
```

Output is:

> ```
> quit: Q 
> state: I 
> quit: Q
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When the Regex returns the matches, you can inspect [the `Index` property in the underlying `Capture` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index?view=net-7.0) to check which position that specific capture/group matched in the original string.

If you are matching against a single stream of commands, if you order the resulting captures/groups by this `Index` it should give you the results in the order they were typed.

Something like this should work:

```
foreach (var group in Regex
    .Match(cmdInput, "your_pattern")
    .Groups
    .Values
    .OrderBy(g => g.Index))
{
    // Use the match here
}
```

This doesn't mean that relying on a Regex is the best approach to parse complex commands like that, but if you want to keep using a single `Regex` for it, this might work.

Comment: The code doesn't deliver what is asked for. Consider an input like "Q I Q" it will only find the Q command once, because it only looks at the groups but not at the captures for every group.